# Inifite Loop in Java Code

Tags: java

I am having a problem in my program concerning an infinite loop as well as a incorrect response. In my program , I am trying to randomly set up ships for a battleship game and I am having problems with the placing the ships part. I have coded it , but I am running into 2 problems , one being that I have an infinite loop somewhere but i dont know where and the next being that the pieces dont properly set up on the grid . I have looked through this code for a  long time and I havent found a fix. Here it is :

```
    public void placeAllShips() {
  int direction = (int) Math.random()*2 ; 
  int p1 = 0 ; 
  int p2 = 0 ; 
  for(int ships = 1 ; ships < 6 ; ships ++ ) { 
   p1 = (int)(Math.random()*10); 
   p2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);  
   if ( p1 !=0 && p2!= 0 && direction == 0 /* Horizontal Direction*/ ){ 
    for(int i= 0; i < ships ; i ++ ){ 
     while(board[p1][p2+i].hasShip() == true || p2 + i > 10 && p2 - i < 0 ){  
      randomize(p1,p2) ;
     }
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < ships ; j ++ ) {
     board[p1][p2+j].setHasShip(true) ; 
    }

   } 
   else if ( p1 !=0 && p2!= 0 && direction == 1 /*Vertical Direction*/ ){ 
    for(int i= 0; i < ships ; i ++ ){ 
     while(board[p1+i][p2].hasShip() == true || p1 + i > 10 && p1 - i < 0 ){  
      randomize(p1,p2) ;
     }
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < ships ; j ++ ) {
     board[p1+j][p2].setHasShip(true) ; 
    }

   }
  }
 } 

 public void randomize( int x , int y ) { 
  //Generates random numbers.
  x = (int)Math.random()*10 ;
  y = (int)Math.random()*10 ;
 }
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Your for loops seam OK, so I would think the problem is in your while loop. If you debug, you can easily see where your infinite loop occurs.

Comment: Did you try to use debugger in order to find out where the infinite loop exists?

Comment: Your 'randomize' method is wrong (I guess, since I don't know your complete use case).
You randomize x and y, but this should be p1 and p2 (I guess)?

Comment: `int direction = (int) Math.random()*2 ;` is the same as writing `int direction = 0;`. Better replace it with `int direction = (int) (Math.random() * 2);`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the infinite loop is caused by not understanding how parameter passing works in Java. Look at this code:

```
// You're calling this if you're trying to use a point which is already taken
randomize(p1,p2) ;

public void randomize( int x , int y ) {
    //Generates random numbers.
    x = (int)Math.random()*10 ;
    y = (int)Math.random()*10 ;
}
```

Aside from the fact that it would be cleaner to use a single instance of `Random` instead of `Math.random()`, your `randomize()` method is fundamentally not doing what you expect it to.

When you call `randomize(p1, p2)` that copies the *values* of `p1` and `p2` into the parameters `x` and `y` as initial values. Changes to `x` and `y` do *not* change `p1` and `p2`... so if you get into that loop at all, it will be infinite as `p1` and `p2` will be the same on every iteration.

To start with, you should probably change your loop to something like:

```
// Put this *outside* the top level loop so you only create a single instance
Random random = new Random();

...

while(p2 + i > 10 || p2 - i < 0 || board[p1][p2+i].hasShip()) {
    p1 = random.nextInt(10);
    p2 = random.nextInt(10);
}
```

That's not going to be the *complete* solution by any means (there are other things wrong with your code) but it's important to try to understand one problem at a time.

(The next thing to think about is the fact that you need to check all the values for a ship at a *single* point - you need to pick a point, then try all the squares a ship at that point would take up, and if you fail you need to start again rather than just trying a different point for that value of `i`.)

Comment: I made that change to my code , but an array out of bounds exception appeared . How will I solve that problem now ??

Comment: @user1810925: Your loop condition was checking the array value before checking whether you were using a valid index at all. I've edited my answer for this, but we're not going to be able to fix this one problem at a time interactively - that's not what Stack Overflow's designed for. You need to look carefully at your program and make sure you understand *every line of it* yourself. Then take a step back and compare it with what you're really trying to achieve. (I think you need a bit of a redesign, not just fiddling with tiny sections.)